# Google Earth Engine Classification with high-res. NAIP-Orthofotos

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, random-forest, naip

i try to perform a supervised classification with Google Earth Engine based on NAIP: National Agriculture Imaginary Progamm orthofotos. These images have a resolution of 1m in 4 Bands (R,G,B,N). I am looking for a classification in Vegetation, Impervious, Water.

I followed the various tutorials on Sentinel-Data. I sampled training data as polygons for the different classes and safed them as FeatureCollections with properties and values. Then I merged them into one collection and continued with sampleRegions. Then i start building the training-process and further to classify the whole image.

Unfortunately i get the Error:  "orthofoto.sampleRegions is not a function"

My code works with Sentinel-Data but it happens to not work with the orthofotos. I Does anyone know how a classification should be done?

This is my work so far:

```
// Imports: FeatureCollections for training data, Property: 'landcover', Value: [0,1,2]
// vegetation: FeatureCollection, landcover:0
// impervious: FeatureCollection, landcover:1
// water: FeatureCollection, landcover:2
 
// Function for clipping image
var clipcol = function(image) {
  var clipimage = image.clip(geometry)
  return clipimage
}

// Import of NAIP-Orthofoto
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(clipcol)

// Just get the second image of the collection             
var listOfImages = dataset.toList(dataset.size());
var orthofoto = listOfImages.get(1)

// True Color Visualisation
var trueColor = dataset.select(['R', 'G', 'B']);
var trueColorVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 255.0,
};
Map.addLayer(trueColor, trueColorVis, 'Orthofoto');

// Band selection and merge of the 3 FeatureCollection
var bands = ['R', 'G', 'B', 'N'];
var merged_collection = impervious.merge(vegetation).merge(water)

// Sample Regions (Error!)
var training = orthofoto.sampleRegions({
  collection: merged_collection,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 1
})

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'landcover',
  inputProperties: bands
})

var classified = dataset.select(bands).classify(classifier)
Map.addLayer(classified, {min:0, max:2, palette: ['green','red','blue']},
"classified image")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68503455/how-to-access-elements-from-a-list-in-google-earth-engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your property 'orthofoto' is a `computedObject`, not an `image`. You can specify the property as an `image` by:

```
var orthofoto = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(1))
```

Alternatively, if it works for your project,  you can take the mean of the dataset using `dataset.mean()` and use that for sampling. Of course, this means that you're sampling across the entire date period and not just the second image in the collection.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your response, it solved my problem and works now fine! Have a great new year!